# SWIG 3.0.x not progressing in code that uses template alias declarations and typedefs. Is it still unsupported?

Tags: c++, ruby, templates, c++11, swig

I read the C++11 documentation for [SWIG 3.0.4 under alias templates](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#CPlusPlus11_alias_templates) and it says they are partially supported.  The documentation lists some warnings and makes the suggestion that code that uses templates should still mostly work.  However, when I try a particular piece of code SWIG claims there's an error on input and stops proceeding.

Here's my test setup, containing 4 files:  Experiment.h, Experiment.cpp, and Experiment.i.

In experiment.h:

```
#ifndef EXPERIMENT_H
#define EXPERIMENT_H

template< typename T >
class MyTemplate {
    T m_MyTemplateVariable;
};

struct Policy {
    template< typename T >
    using PolicyTemplate = MyTemplate<T>;
};

template< typename Policy, typename T >
class TestClass {
    public:
        typedef typename Policy::template PolicyTemplate< T > InternalTemplate;
        TestClass() {}
    private:
        InternalTemplate m_TestMember;
};

#endif
```

In experiment.cpp:

```
#include "Experiment.h"

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    TestClass< Policy, int > inttest;
    TestClass< Policy, float > floattest;

    return 0;
}
```

And in Experiment.i, I have this:

```
%module Experiment
%{

#include "Experiment.h"

%}

%include "Experiment.h"

%template( IntTestClass ) TestClass< Policy, int >;
%template( FloatTestClass ) TestClass< Policy, float >;
```

When I compile, I use `c++ -o Experiment -std=c++11 Experiment.cpp`.  The code compiles.  When I run swig, I get:

```
Experiment.h:11: Warning 342: The 'using' keyword in template aliasing is not fully supported yet.
Experiment.h:17: Error: Syntax error in input(3).
```

The warning 342 is expected, as specified in the documentation.  It's the syntax error part that was unexpected, and that happens to be on this line:

```
    typedef typename Policy::template PolicyTemplate< T > InternalTemplate;
```

Is there a work around for this problem?  Shouldn't SWIG just not add it to the type system and move on, like it claims in the documentation?  Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.  If it matters, I'm trying to target ruby and python.  I apologize in advance if I overlooked something silly.

Comment: Not a solution, but an observation: The complicated dependant names is being reported as a syntax error. SWIG accepts (but doesn't do what you'd hope) it without the `typename` and `template` keywords on that line.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I suspect this is a bug related to parsing, but didn't want to label it as such until some other people examined it also.